# Intel HD graphics Kext on OpenCore Ventura on Macbook Pro 2012

Tags: macbook-pro, macos-ventura, old-hardware

I've just installed Ventura on my Macbook Pro 2012 (MacBookPro9,2 - Ivy Bridge) using OpenCore Legacy Patcher (v 1.2.1).
So far so good, but there's a problem with drivers for Intel Graphics card.
Every time I boot, OpenCore tells me that `Root patch` is required to install Ivy Bridge graphics

[image: OpenCore root to install Root Patches]

I did that a couple of times, even by running OpenCore app from Safe mode. It didn't help.

System information on Ventura displays this:

```
  Type: GPU
  Bus:  Built-In
  VRAM (Total): 3 MB
  VRAM (Dynamic, Max):  
  Vendor:   Intel
  Device ID:    0x0166
  Revision ID:  0x0009
  Kernel Extension Info:    No Kext Loaded
```

Since apparently drivers are not loaded, then screen dimming doesn't work, and hibernation doesn't turn off the screen, and of course the UI is a bit sluggish.

I've googled a lot, and found no solution so far or similar thread related to Intel HD graphics (Intel HD Graphics 4000?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem and solution.

Intel HD Graphics 4000 works on MacBookPro9,2 when using OpenCore Legacy Patcher (v 1.2.1).

The problem was while building Root Patches, there was an error that I ignored that stopped the proper patch (even though the Patcher was happy to continue): [image: Logs from Root Patcher]

I needed to find this driver, tried to remove it using [WD support page](https://support-in.wd.com/app/answers/detailweb/a_id/51137/%7E/steps-to-uninstall-wd-drive-utilities-or-wd-security-software-on-macos) but it didn't work.

Great thanks to support from `OCLP` via discord, where I was informed to remove all `Kext` files from `/Library/Extensions` except for HighPoint* and SoftRAID*, like so [image: OCLP infographic]

After removal of those unneeded (backup them just in case) I was able to run Root Patching without errors by opening OCLP app. What was left was to Install the Patch and proper `Kext` were loaded - acceleration works, hibernation works, brightness changing works.